# Relation between AspNetIdentity database and IdentityServer3.EntityFramework database?

Tags: identityserver3

I have used IdentityServer3.EntityFramework library to keep all configuration in SQL database. Also I'm using IdentityServer3.AspNetIdentity plugin for identity management. I can't find out how to link / map these 2 database together. I mean base on which concepts.
Do I need to have UserId in Config database or should I match user claims with config claims ?

Comment: They are unrelated, except that they are both connect to databases.

Comment: Thanks Brock. I think there is ambiguity is my question or misunderstanding. When i use AspNetIdentity i have my User ( username/password ) and user role / claims in that database. Also i have my client / scope / claims inside config database by using  IdentityServer3.EntityFramework. Lets say question is what's difference between claims in  AspNetIdentity  database and Client/Scope claims in config database. if there are related then how ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your request from client application contains scopes, you store them as role/claims in asp.net identity database. Then compare with scope table in IdentityServer3.EntityFramework database.

Answer (score 2):

The claims in the ASP.NET Identity database are claims about that user. This will include a claim type and a claim value (e.g. `given_name` and `scott`).

The scope claims within the IdentityServer scopes are what claim types a token can contain if the token has that scope. This is only ever a claim type (e.g. if I request a token with the `profile` scope, it can contain a users `given_name`).

The client claims within the IdentityServer client applications are what hardcoded claims that client application will receive in a token. This will include a claim type and a claim value (e.g. `client_name` and `mvcapp`).